# How do I find the number of windows of a certain program that are open in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to AHK and would like to find the number of windows of a certain program open at any time and store that in a variable.

I have a script that opens an Opera window when I press the caps lock key, but I would only like three of these windows open at any one time, so when there are more than three Opera windows open and I press the caps lock key it does nothing.

I would also like the caps lock button never to capitalise text (in other words, to have caps lock state always off)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WinGet` with the `Count` operation (see [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#Count)) to get the number of windows matching a certain filter.

You need to find the right filter of course. You can use the Window Spy utility for that which comes with AutoHotkey.

In this case I already did it: You'll see that the window class (`ahk_class`) of the Opera windows is `Chrome_WidgetWin_1`. However, this would be true for Chrome, Chromium, etc. as well, so we further have to filter for the program EXE filename (`ahk_exe`) of `opera.exe`. (The reason we don't *just* filter by `ahk_exe` is that we don't want to include things like an "there are updates available" box or whatever other non-main window Opera may have open, I guess.)

The final result is:

```
WinGet cnt, Count, ahk_exe opera.exe ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
MsgBox There are %cnt% Opera windows open
```

Comment: To have caps lock state always off see [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm).

Comment: @user3419297 I'm assuming this would only set the caps lock state always off after I press the caps key? Is it ok in AHk to just have ```SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff``` without a hotkey above it?

Comment: Yes, it's a general setting to just disable the regular caps lock functionality. It exist independently from hotkeys you may have defined on `Caps`.

Comment: This command has to be put in the [autoexecute-section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script before the first hotkey, hotstring or return).